# Azure Device Provisioning to Edge Device

Tags: azure, iot

I am trying to figure out how to use DPS to pass down to a device which edge device to connect to. Is this an option to do with DPS or do we have do to this manually?

Answer (score 0):

- The DPS is a helper service for IoT hub that will provide the right IoT hub without requiring human intervention

> The IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service (DPS) is a helper service for IoT Hub that enables zero-touch, just-in-time provisioning to the right IoT hub without requiring human intervention.

- Below are the scenarios in which DPS is an excellent choice for getting devices connected and configured to IoT Hub.
- Zero-touch provisioning to a single IoT solution without hardcoding IoT Hub connection information at the factory (initial setup)
- Load-balancing devices across multiple hubs
- Connecting devices to their owner's IoT solution based on sales transaction data (multitenancy)
- Connecting devices to a particular IoT solution depending on use-case (solution isolation)
- Connecting a device to the IoT hub with the lowest latency (geo-sharding)
- Reprovisioning based on a change in the device
- Rolling the keys used by the device to connect to IoT Hub (when not using X.509 certificates to connect)

Here are a few references which have the complete information on DPS.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/

Comment: So from what it sounds like I would use DPS to provision the device to the hub and then have the device request a connection an edge device and pass that down from the hub for future communication?